# Using OFFSET-FETCH, how to default number of rows to "all rows"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Envision a stored procedure which takes `@skip` (offset) and `@take` (maximum number of rows to return. If `@take` is `null`, then I want to return "all rows after applying the offset".

I can accomplish this by counting the number of rows in the table/view if `@take` is `null`, but then I have to perform two queries which is, of course, not optimal. I was hoping there was an option similar to `FETCH [NEXT] ALL ROWS`.

```
DECLARE @skip BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @take BIGINT = NULL;

IF (@take IS NULL) SET @take = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable);

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SortOrder
OFFSET @skip ROWS
FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
DECLARE @skip BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @take BIGINT = NULL;

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SortOrder
OFFSET COALESCE(@skip,0) ROWS
FETCH NEXT COALESCE(@take,0x7ffffff) ROWS ONLY
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423015)**</kbd>

`0x7ffffff` is the same as `2147483647` max `INT` value.

When `@skip` and `@take` are not provided it will get first 2^31-1 records from table.

Comment: Thanks, the general concept works. However, the default "take" value would have to be `ABS(min_value) + max_value` for the data type, or 0xFFFFFFFF for INT and 0x10000000000000000 for BIGINT. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JoshM. The default value for @take can be anything big enough. If you have table bigger than 2mld records (IDENTITY column overflow) feel free to use 2^63-1 `FETCH NEXT COALESCE(@take,CAST(9223372036854775807 AS BIGINT) ) ROWS ONLY`

Comment: My point was that it's actually 2x the size of BIGINT. Because there could be that many records. This is assuming your PK is BIGINT and you're using negative IDs. It's an edge case, I know, but worth mentioning. The only other issue is if you're using some composite key on a very large table. But you probably don't really want "all rows" in this case anyway.

Comment: @JoshM. If your PK is BIGINT it has range: -2^63 up to 2^63-1. Do you really use negative values as PK? I have to admit I don't see that case because same 2^63-1 is hard enough to imagine.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, was just saying it *could* be an issue. However, turns out the `FETCH NEXT` clause requires an `INT` anyway! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply omit the `FETCH` in the case where you want all rows:

```
DECLARE @skip BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @take BIGINT = NULL;

IF (@take IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable
    ORDER BY SortOrder
    OFFSET @skip ROWS
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable
    ORDER BY SortOrder
    OFFSET @skip ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY
END
```

Comment: I definitely don't want to duplicate the query (supposed there's more to my query than I posted) or write dynamic SQL. Thank you though.